# Excel VBA If Statements with Only Visible Cells

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm trying to write a code that uses if statements on a Filtered Field which will find the First Letter value of a specific range of cells and If that letter falls into a specific range then I want to ouput a specific person's initials.

My code is:

```
Sub NewFilter()
Dim wbI As Workbook, wb0 As Workbook
Dim wsI As Worksheet, ws0 As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range
Dim outputRange As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Establish my source of info worbooks and worksheet
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Filters Original wb by criteria
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Gur Insurance Plan 1", "Gur Insurance Plan 2", "Gur Insurance Plan 3", _
    "Gur Insurance Plan 4", "Gur Insurance Pol No 1", "Gur Insurance Pol No 2", _
    "Gur Insurance Pol No 3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Establish and create new worbook where I will output my info
Set wb0 = Workbooks.Add

With wb0

'Save new workbook
Set ws0 = wb0.Sheets("Sheet1")
.SaveAs Filename:="New Soarian Test"

'Copy all visible cells in original workbook
wsI.Cells.Copy

'Paste values and formatting rules into new workbook
ws0.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ws0.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 End With

    'Add a new column into A called "Rep"
ws0.Columns("A:A").InsertShift:=xlToRight,                                       CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ws0.Range("A1").Value = "Rep"

'Filter Soarian Column by "Approved"
Selection.AutoFilter
ws0.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
     "APPROVED"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Select and delete cells then unfilter all
ws0.Range("A2:I1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ws0.AutoFilterMode = False

'Filter EncProv by Clincal Psych and Physcial Therapy
ws0.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
     "PHYSICAL THERAPY", "CLINIC PSYCH OUTPAT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Select visible cells and delete them and then unfilter
ws0.Range("A2:I1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ws0.AutoFilterMode = False

'Filter EncProv by NPL Endo
ws0.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
      "NPL ENDOCRINOLOGY"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ws0.Range("A1").Select

Set myRange = Range("E2:E1000" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End    (xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set outputRange = Range("A2:A1000" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count
    If Left(myRange.Cells(i, j).Value, 1) >= "A" And Left(myRange.Cells(i,  j).Value, 1) <= "K" Then
            outputRange.Cells(i, j).Value = "MCJ"
    End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I commented it for the most part for an easier read but I'm only concerned with the last part of the code where I set my ranges.  I want it to only follow the if statements for the cells that are showing after the filter is applied.  It works inputs the person's initials correctly for the most part but there are still cells in column A that are not populating correctly even though the Letter I look up falls between A and K.  Any ideas?

(I'm a novice with VBA and realize that some of my tactics my not be as efficient as they could be)

Thank you very much!